# next.js pass props from HOC to child components getInitialProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'd like to create an HOC for pages in my app that supplies some information kept in local storage for the case when the pages are not rendered on the server.

I am only able to actually set the data from `componentDidMount` because I need access to localStorage (not avail. in Node env. obviously).

```
import * as React from 'react'
const withLogin = Page => class SecurePage extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps (ctx) {

    let language;
    if (ctx.req) {
        language = ctx.req.session.language;
    } else {
        language = localStorage.getItem('language');
    }

    let props = {}
    if (Page.getInitialProps) {
        const pageProps = await Page.getInitialProps(ctx);
        props = { ...pageProps, language }
    }

    console.log("this is what the props look like in the wrapping component", props)

    return props;

    // return Page.getInitialProps && { ...(await Page.getInitialProps(ctx)), language }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
      const { language } = this.props;
      if (language) {
          /* if we were able to fetch the language, set it here */
          localStorage.setItem('language', language);
      }
  }

  render () {
      console.log("pre-render page props ", this.props);
    return <Page {...this.props} /> 
  }
}

export default withLogin
```

When I go to outfit a component with it, the HOC getInitialProps function runs as expected, but it has no impact on the getInitialProps function of the rendered component. **Is there no way for me to pass props to the getInitialProps of a child component through HOC pattern?**

```
class EmployerJobList extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps(props) {

        if (props.req) {
            /* SSR */
            // language = req.session.language;
        } else {
            /* non-SSR */
            // language = user.preferred_language;
        }
        console.log("got language", props.language); // => undefined
        getUrl (`/api/localization?filename=create-job&language=${props.language}`)
        .then( jsonRes => {
            console.log(jsonRes);
        })
        ...
     export default withLogin(EmployerJobList)
```

If this is not a viable pattern; is there any reliable way for me to share/reuse the logic I am aiming for here with localStorage?

I could theoretically do this in each Page component:

```
static async getInitialProps(props) {

    let language;
    if (props.req) {
        /* SSR */
        language = req.session.language;
    } else {
        /* non-SSR */
        language = localStorage.getItem('language') // works
    }
    ...
```

But that seems unnecessarily redundant.

Answer (score 7):

Was able to pass values into the child's `getInitialProps` function by supplying them as arguments:

```
  static async getInitialProps (ctx) {
    let language;
    if (ctx.req) {
        language = ctx.req.session.language;
    } else {
        language = localStorage.getItem('language');
    }
    let props = {}
    if (Page.getInitialProps) {
        const pageProps = await Page.getInitialProps(ctx, language); // <--- this
        props = { ...pageProps, language }
    }
    return props;
  }
```

Then in the child component's getInitialProps I could access the new argument:

```
static async getInitialProps({ query }, language) {

    console.log("is language passed through: ", language); // "en"
    const jobStatus = query.jobStatus;

    return { jobStatus }
}
```

Comment: Super helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @Danial Thompson: Danial, I have used getInitialProps in my _app.js and passed some data to its child. Just like the way you have proposed, and it works in child component by using getInitialProps. Although going forward with next.js > 9.3 I've tried to use getServerSideProps with no success. Do you have any idea for that perhaps? Need to mention that getServerSideProps hasn't been introduce to _app.js yet and I had to stick to getInitialProps. But in the child component I can use getServerSideProps and I'm looking for a solution to get the data form _app there. Any Ideas?

Comment: Thanks! I made a slight modification on my side: `const pageProps = await Page.getInitialProps({ ...ctx, language });` so that the added props become part of the first argument and you can do `getInitialProps({ query, language })`.